# How to write data in a PostgreSQL C extension?

Tags: c, postgresql, postgresql-extensions

I am writing an extension function in C for PostgreSQL. 
I can find lots of examples online but nothing that explicitly shows how to actually write data to a table in an extension function?

Where do I need to look to find the right functionality/documentation for writing a record to an existing table as a C extension?

Answer (score 3):

I should've googled a bit longer before posting. 
It seems that SPI fits my needs exactly

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi.html